# Gdal in ipython gives ImportError?

Tags: gdal, installation, ipython

i am trying to run GDAL in Ipython Notebook but i don't get it.

I did conda install GDAL and it was aparently ok, but when i try to do the import i get this:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-27bf4694dd2b> in <module>()
----> 1 import gdal

C:\Users\Usuario\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\gdal.py in <module>()
      1 # import osgeo.gdal as a convenience
----> 2 from osgeo.gdal import deprecation_warn
      3 deprecation_warn('gdal')
      4 
      5 from osgeo.gdal import *

C:\Users\Usuario\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py in <module>()
     19                 fp.close()
     20             return _mod
---> 21     _gdal = swig_import_helper()
     22     del swig_import_helper
     23 else:

C:\Users\Usuario\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py in swig_import_helper()
     15         if fp is not None:
     16             try:
---> 17                 _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
     18             finally:
     19                 fp.close()

ImportError: DLL load failed: No se encontró el proceso especificado.
```

Any idea please?

Comment: Your module is not correctly installed (no GDAL library, so no dll...)

Comment: [![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GYgfe.png)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GYgfe.png) I had the same issue..
from osgeo import gdal works in python shell.. but fail in ipython..

Comment: I solved the issue....
I reinstalled the entire python modules and and also reset the environment variables and got the solution....[![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mkdSU.png)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mkdSU.png)